# (SQL) Delete all rows except the newest one

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have a problem, namely I'm deleting all rows from the table except for the newest one. I do not know too much how to construct the appropriate query.

The look of the table structure:

```
| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 |
| --------|---------|---------|---------|
| aaa     | aaa     | aaa     | aaa     | 
| bbb     | bbb     | bbb     | bbb     |
| ccc     | ccc     | ccc     | ccc     |
```

Suppose line 3 was added last, which is the latest one. After the query:

```
| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 |
| --------|---------|---------|---------|
| ccc     | ccc     | ccc     | ccc     |
```

Comment: Do you have same values in all rows or different values?

Comment: @Rtra No, not the same value.

Comment: You can find my answer with an explanation so understand in detail

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to delete all the rows the SQL is :

```
Delete  from theTable;
```

If you want to exclude the newest, hoping that you have an id you write like this:

```
Delete  from theTable where id <> (Select max (id) from theTable)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had to modify the query a bit, but it works as it should, thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Taking into consideration the above answers (which are correct) you could additionally set a limit on your inner select and an order by the unique field you want to use. in order to keep the row you want to keep and delete all the others.

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE column1 NOT IN (SELECT column1 FROM tablename order by column1 desc LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have two different solutions for this, If you want to delete all rows except the last, then first find total number of rows in that table, then delete all rows except the highest value this the first solution you should use this

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE column1 NOT IN (SELECT MAX(column1) column1 FROM tablename)
```

Second if you have any specific unique values then select all rows against the unique value then delete then you need to define it in your SELECT statement

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE column2='anyvalue' AND column1 NOT IN (SELECT MAX(column1) column1 FROM tablename)
```